# Large records to insert AWS DynamoDB with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services

I have a csv file with about 400000 rows that I need to process and insert to AWS DynamoDB table. What will be the best way to do it?

I tried to do with a foreach and PutRequest it only created about 6348 rows. Is there anything that I need to taken care of?

Comment: use insert_batch 400K rows isn't that big, it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [batch inserts](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert), take a look at [CLI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html).

1. Limit your inserts ( 4k? per script load ) and run it via CLI
2. Create batches in separate files and insert them (batches) one by one.
3. do it tomorrow
4. or combination of first 2

---

CLI should run "forever" it has no time limits, also take a look in [here](http://www.daharveyjr.com/codeigniter-cli-command-line-interface/).

Comment: I have used this batch_insert in CI, but will it work for AWS DynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

With Amazon DynamoDB, a request will fail if you have exceeded your provisioned throughput. If your DynamoDB table was configured with Amazon CloudWatch, you should be able to see if this is the case by going to the AWS Management Console. Do you need to increase your write throughput capacity?

Are you using the AWS SDK for PHP? If so, then your single `PutItem` requests will be retried a few times if they fail, but the SDK will also eventually give up too if it keeps getting rejected due to exceeding your throughput.

Are you using single requests via the `PutItem` API or batches of puts via the `BatchWriteItem` API? You should probably read about and use the latter.

**However, the best way to do this** is to use the `WriteRequestBatch` abstraction that ships as part of the AWS SDK for PHP. It uses the `BatchWriteItem` API internally and also queues and manages the requests to make sure that all of the items get written. Please see the [Using the WriteRequestBatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/service-dynamodb.html#using-the-writerequestbatch) section of the [AWS SDK for PHP User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/).

Comment: Hei Jeremy, I have used BatchWriteItem  and its worked. :) Thanks for clarifying things.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve them using a 'code'scan query? Want to retrieve them with group by method is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are wanting to do or what you mean by "group by" in the context of a non-relational database. I suggest you look at the AWS documentation to learn more about scan vs. query though: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html

Answer (score 0):

When doing a bulk data load, another thing to keep in mind with Amazon DynamoDB is your distribution of writes across unique hash key values.  If your data is sorted by hash key value, and you have 10,000 items all with the same hash key one after another, then uploading the data sequentially could create an uneven workload and thereby cause throttling.  To make the most of your throughput in DynamoDB, it is a best practice to spread your writes evenly across your hash keys.  In practice, this may involve breaking up your file into many separate files (as Kyslik mentions above), and uploading them in parallel and out of order.

More details are available in the [DynamoDB Developer Guide Best Practices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BestPractices.html), particularly [Distribute Write Activity During Data Upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.DataUpload)

Comment: Yes Dzavid, I have experienced this situation. Thanks for the tip.